# How to fetch CoinEx API with access ID and secret key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch using the CoinEx API and get account info but I receive an error.

API Documentation :

[API Invocation Description](https://github.com/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki/012security_authorization)

[Acquire Market Statistics](https://github.com/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki/021ticker)

[Inquire Account Info](https://github.com/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki/060balance)

Note : This account is only for test (Sharing access ID and secret key in public)

```
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/md5.js"></script>
<script>
let ServerTime=0;
let AccessID="61CFB9AB7F0B46B18F26EE2E3F155F4C";
let SecretKey="109E2A9E37DD4257D4C6DEDFE3F261A269EEB98DAA48B3E1";
let Signature=CryptoJS.MD5(SecretKey).toString().toUpperCase();

Process();
async function Process()
{
await MarketStatistics();
await AccountInfo(ServerTime,AccessID,SecretKey,Signature);
}

async function MarketStatistics()
{
let MarketStatistics_Fetch=await fetch("https://api.coinex.com/v1/market/ticker/all");
let MarketStatistics_JSON=await MarketStatistics_Fetch.json();

ServerTime=parseInt(MarketStatistics_JSON.data.date);
}

async function AccountInfo(ServerTime,AccessID,SecretKey,Signature)
{
let AccountInfo_Fetch=await fetch("https://api.coinex.com/v1/balance/info"+"?"+"access_id="+AccessID+"&"+"tonce="+ServerTime+"&"+"secret_key="+SecretKey,{method:"get",headers:{"authorization":Signature}});
let AccountInfo_JSON=await AccountInfo_Fetch.json();

alert(AccountInfo_JSON.message);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Result : Signature error.

Answer (score 1):

You are seemingly "signing" (hashing with `MD5`) only the secret key.

On the link you provided, it is clearly detailed that you should hash *either* the whole _query string), with the arguments in order (it is shown in the "**Generate String To Sign**" section).

You should do something like

```js
let queryString = "access_id="+AccessID+"&"+"tonce="+ServerTime+"&"+"secret_key="+SecretKey
let Signature=CryptoJS.MD5(queryString).toString().toUpperCase();
```

then append this `queryString` to your `fetch()` URL argument.